# Convert string array that contains '[' , ']' to int array

Tags: python

I'm attempting to convert an array of strings to array of floats using :

```
arr_str = '[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]'

a1 = arr_str.split()

[int(x) for x in a1]
```

but throws error :

<

```
ipython-input-57-f7f1eaba7ebd> in <listcomp>(.0)
      3 a1 = arr_str.split()
      4 
----> 5 [int(x) for x in a1]
      6 
      7 # for a in arr_str.split():

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[1'
```

Should pre-process the string and remove '[' and ']' ?

Comment: Can you add a space between the `[` and the first `1`? Then your list comprehension will look like: `[int(x) for x in a1[1:-1]`.  Preprocessing the string to remove the `[` and `]` would work as well

Comment: use arr_str.strip('[]').split()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `ast.literal_eval`.

If you need a `numpy` integer array, the conversion is trivial.

```
import numpy as np
from ast import literal_eval

arr_str = '[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]'

res = literal_eval(arr_str.replace(' ', ','))

# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

res_np = np.array(res)

# array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr_str = arr_str.strip("[]")
voila = [int(x) for x in arr_str.split()]
```

Edit 1: Being pedantic about variable assignment.

Comment: Thanks friend. According to op's string and Python2.7.8, my strip statement works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ast` module:

```
import ast

arr_str = '[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]'

arr = ast.literal_eval(arr_str.replace(" ",", "))
arr = list(map(float,arr)) #Remove this line if you wish integer conversion.
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

since you say `int` in the title, but `float` in your description.